# Objective-C : ActionSheet Dismissing Keyboard?

Tags: ios, objective-c

In my app I have a Chat interface with a simple UITextView acting as the text input.

With the UITextView as first responder and the keyboard visible, I present the following ActionSheet to the user with some options. However, when the ActionSheet is presented, the Keyboard is dismissed and the textview is resigned as first responder. How can I edit this behavior to keep the keyboard visible while presenting the ActionSheet?

```
UIAlertController *actionSheet = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:nil message:nil preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];

[actionSheet addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"copy", @"") style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {

// copy text

}]];

[actionSheet setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationPopover];

UIPopoverPresentationController *popPresenter = [actionSheet popoverPresentationController];
popPresenter.sourceView = self.optionsButton;
popPresenter.sourceRect = self.optionsButton.bounds;

[self presentViewController:actionSheet animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: you have to change  UIAlertController , because  UIAlertController is just ViewController and you present it so this normal behaviour  , so try to create custom action sheet as UIVIew

Comment: Why are you presenting a `UIAlertController` with just a "copy" action? And you seem to be presenting it from a button? What's the benefit of the action sheet?